# Redsocks2 config file location

Tags: configuration

I want to use the redsocks2 software to allow for internet redirection thru a proxy. I have managed to install it and in the git documentation the configuration for this appears easy.

Redsocks2 respository:

https://github.com/semigodking/redsocks

My problem is that i just don't know where to put the config file or the name that it should have

Comment: What was wrong with installation from [the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=redsocks)? It has two configuration files [in `/etc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/redsocks/filelist).

Comment: @N0rbert Am a newbie. You can make this the answer, but please make it comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many software applications are packaged and exist in the official repositories.

The RedSocks is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=redsocks) for all current Ubuntu versions.

To install it you need to execute the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redsocks
```

According to its [file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/redsocks/filelist) it has configuration files in the `/etc` folder:

- /etc/default/redsocks
- /etc/redsocks.conf

The details about the application may found in `man redsocks` (or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/redsocks.8.html)). Also configuration files usually contain comments, so such files are self-explaining.

Comment: redsocks2 is a fork of redsocks, it's not the same package. I am trying to make it work too, it's not just as straightforward as the original package.

Answer (score 1):

We are trying the same thing, I use Manjaro and the configuration file are located (installing redsocks2 from AUR) in the following directory:
/etc/redsocks2.conf

But if you want to use it in Ubuntu I think you will have to compile it from the source (redsocks2).

Once you have installed it (you have to disable shadowsocks) then you will find an example configuration file in
/usr/share/doc/redsocks2/redsocks2.conf.example

The novelty of redsocks2 is that it allows you to use it together with openssl, passing the entire connection of the computer through it.

Please, if you have made progress in the configuration, share it. Tomorrow I will try redsocks2, hopefully it works.